How do I repair a corrupt packed object error during a clean GIT pull
I have a Git repo on Azure DevOps that is nothing but third party code.  Header files and binaries.  But twice today I have tried a clean pull from Azure using Tortoise Git.  But when the pull finishes, I get an error that says one of the packed files in the repo is corrupt.  Yet even after following the suggestions I am stuck and I do not know how to proceed.
Here is the full text of the error I see in Tortoise Git when doing the clone
git.exe clone --progress -v -- "https://mycompany@dev.azure.com/mycompany/Software/_git/SdkThirdParty" "C:\Users\joe\source\repos\SdkThirdParty"
Cloning into 'C:\Users\joe\source\repos\SdkThirdParty'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 55264 to 27730 bytes)
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 15861 objects to send. (91 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (15861/15861), 3.92 GiB | 8.81 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6988/6988), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
fatal: packed object 9c4be69232392eff1184082528a78564ca432605 (stored in C:/Users/joe/source/repos/SdkThirdParty/.git/objects/pack/pack-d1cef48443304ae7ba2fa27b0b4992c1ea61ca05.pack) is corrupt
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

So I followed their suggestions using the command line.  First I tried issuing git status.  It scrolled through a bunch of information messages about deleted files, things I long ago deleted from the repo so this looked good.  At the end it dumped this.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        OpenCV/
        README.md
        arrayfire/

Next I tried following the suggestion to do git restore --source=HEAD :/ and I got this
C:\Users\joe\source\repos\SdkThirdParty>git checkout master
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
fatal: packed object 9c4be69232392eff1184082528a78564ca432605 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-d1cef48443304ae7ba2fa27b0b4992c1ea61ca05.pack) is corrupt

So yes, that file is corrupt.  Is there any way to... decorrupt it?  Should I try to add the untracked files and then proceed?
Not sure where to go from here.

Looks the pack file is corrupted during decompression, please try to git clone the repo again to a new folder, and git pull for a check, will it work?

In addition, please try to delete the pack file on local(.git/objects/pack/pack-d1c...), and git pull  after git clone, it will fetch again the code, check if it fixes.

Got back to this today.  I tried to follow your suggestions.  1. Did a git clone.  It worked just fine.  2. I then did a git pull.  It just said "already up to date".  Strange, I was expecting an error.  3. Then I looked for that pack file that you told me to delete.  There were such files there but with different names.  4. Finally I cloned it the way I did yesterday.  With Tortoise Git.  It worked fine.    So now I am completely mystified.  I tried this 3 times yesterday and it failed.   Nothing has changed but now it works.  Could this be related to the cloud issues Microsoft was having?

Glad to know it works now! I add the details in the answer, thanks.

Typically, the corrupted object could be caused by the aborted transfer.
It could be a temporary incident from DevOps, but also could be the bad network performance.
You can try below options:

It's safe to remove the local corrupted object file,then you can try to git pull or git fetch to get the files again.

Or you can git clone the repo again to a new folder, check if it fixes.


You can check similar ticket for your reference.
